# UnauthorizedAccessException. Can't write to server c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a c# program that attempts to create a pdf on a web server.  I have the correct permissions but it keeps throwing an exception

```
 PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("//share/Document" + "/TestDoc.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

I get an unauthorizedAccessException, and dont know how to proceed

Comment: Is the folder on the server actually shared?

Comment: I can access it no bother using the file explorer

Comment: It's different for you to access it than for your website to access it. I've had this issue before, once it was because I forgot to click "share with everybody" on the folder itself on the server, another time when it was on a server I didn't control I had to pass in credentials in order to access the folder with the web app. Not sure what your situation is with the server...

Comment: Do you have write access or just read access to that folder?

Comment: The user your AppPool is running as needs write access to that UNC share.

Comment: I have full r/w access and the "share with everybody" option was also selected

Comment: @JaimeTorres can you elaborate please

Comment: Does using backslashes for accessing the file system make any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Advanced Settings on the AppPool and scroll down until you find "Identity." That's the user that needs permissions.

Comment: Sorry, where can I find this using VS2013?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you were doing this directly from Visual Studio. By default, that should be your user account. When you deploy it to IIS for production, then it will run under the configured AppPool. When you browse to that location, does it make you enter credentials?